# Binding still works after watcher unbound

Tags: angularjs

I saw this [code example](http://codepen.io/aronrodrigues/pen/mKpoH) online. What the author did is unbind the watcher on `clickCount` when it is more than 4.

```
var unbindWatcher = $scope.$watch(
  "clickCount",
  function(newClickCount) {
    console.log("Watching click count.");
    if (newClickCount >= 5) {
      $scope.isShowingFeedback = true;
      unbindWatcher();
    }
  }
);
```

When the watcher is already unbound, changing `clickCount` in model still results in its change in view. So why binding from model to view is still working? Thanks!

Comment: `{{ clickCount }}` generates a watch. `$scope.$watch` generates another watch. Neither of these watches are two ways bindings. You have control **only** over what you created with `$scope.$watch`

Comment: If you do `console.log($scope.$$watchers)` inside `unbindWatcher` function ..you will see the effect as @LuisMasuelli said

Comment: @LuisMasuelli  Thanks so much. Can you post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Answer posted. With more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having **two** watches here.

1. `{{ clickCount }}`, which shows in screen the `$scope.clickCount` variable everytime it changes. You **never** have control on such watch, until the `{{ clickCount }}` fragment is removed via directive (e.g. `ng-if`). Yes: `{{ stuff }}` is a read-only binding and every binding is a stuff.
2. The directive you created with `$scope.$watch`. You are controlling that directive and it is being deleted as you commanded. In this way: the console message is created 6 times: 1 when the watch is created, and 5 for each number increment (initial variable value is 0, so... 0-1, 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5 are 5 times).

But there's something you don't have control over by the way you used:

```
<a ng-click="incrementCount()">Click it, click it real good!</a>
```

`incrementCount()` is **always** executed, on each click. So you are updating the variable **which is being always updated by the first watch, which you cannot control as long as it is there**.

My suggestion: change `incrementCount` logic to increment only if `!$scope.isShowingFeedback`.

**notes**: You don't have any two-ways binding here. Two-ways bindings can exist only in directives (e.g. `ng-model="myvar"` is a directive named ngModel which has a two-ways binding with the attribute `ng-model` in the DOM; this creates a two-ways binding watcher) and allow both read and edition on parent scope attributes. This is not the case, so try fixing your question accordingly: you have two separate watchers, one of them corresponding to one-way binding.